# PS Try-catch in VS Code call to Get-Mailbox don't catch error

Tags: powershell, try-catch, visual-studio-code, office365

I have a funktion to list all email-addresses on a specified user in Office365 and I use this function to check if an email-address is available.

Why is the Try-Catch not working in VS Code but in PS ISE?

```
Function ListAllEmailAdresses
{
  param ($ID)
  Try
  {
    $Mailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity $ID -ErrorAction Stop
    $VarUser = Get-User -Identity $ID -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Output "Email is occupied by: $Mailbox, $($VarUser.Title)"
    Write-Output $Mailbox.EmailAddresses
  }
  Catch
  {
    Write-Output "E-mail $ID is available"
  }
}
```

when calling this function in VS Code the Try-Catch is not working.

```
PS C:\script> ListAllEmailAdresses -ID 'lidingo@elon.se'
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'lidingo@elon.se' couldn't be found on 'VI1PR03DC0025.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com'.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=VI1PR03MB3165,RequestId=62016320-c687-41ed-9949-4b0fe854d821,TimeStamp=2017-08-09 13:54:40] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 2CD51ECE,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
+ PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

The operation couldn't be performed because object 'lidingo@elon.se' couldn't be found on 'VI1PR03DC0025.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com'.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-User], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=VI1PR03MB3165,RequestId=db435869-8b64-4edf-bb90-a2eb836b07fa,TimeStamp=2017-08-09 13:54:41] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] DAFB12B9,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetUser
+ PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

Email is occupied by: ,
```

The PS Error say that the called E-mailadrdress could not be found and therefore it should got to the Catch-code. But it doesnt :(

If I call the same function in Powershell ISE I get this result:

```
PS C:\Script> ListAllEmailAdresses -ID 'lidingo@elon.se'
E-mail lidingo@elon.se is available
```

The PS Error is catched and I get the wanted output.

/Anders

Comment: I've noticed some really annoying bugs with VSCode's PowerShell host.  It's an inconsistency you may not find an answer to.  I'd recommend testing your scripts in an independent PowerShell session.  For example, I recently ran across a case where I was getting no output when trying to pipe a command or assign it in VSCode, but it worked fine in ISE/console.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Since it is working in an ISE-session but not VS Code-session I will just go over to GitHub and report is as a bug.

Comment: Reference the issue was resolved via the GitHub issue submitted: [vscode-powershell issue #991](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/991) Which I had a hunch when you noted Office 365 it was because of the remote execution of commands.